# How can I group Standard Deviation of multiple sets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, match, stdev

I have a group of respondents (e.g. 4), each answering a few questions (e.g. 10 questions).
The questions belong to 3 groups (Basic, Advanced, Other).
I want to calculate the Standard deviation for each group (STDev for the Basic questions, STDev for the Advanced questions, STDev for the Other questions).
How can I do that?

Here's an example google sheet, where A:K are the answers of the respondents and M:N is the grouping of the different questions. I want the Standard deviations, per group, in column Q using a formula.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10CjMTFVU5qmGbKmqeo2FxuSf2G712cKxYliBN0cE7KU/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=STDEV(FLATTEN(FILTER(B$2:K$5, REGEXMATCH(B$1:K$1&"", 
 "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, ""&FILTER(M$2:M$11, N$2:N$11=P2))&"$"))))
```

arrayformula:

```
=BYROW(P2:P4, LAMBDA(x, STDEV(FLATTEN(FILTER(B$2:K$5, REGEXMATCH(B$1:K$1&"", 
 "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, ""&FILTER(M$2:M$11, N$2:N$11=x))&"$"))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=STDEV(FILTER(B2:K5,XMATCH(B1:K1,FILTER(M2:M11,N2:N11=P2))))
```

- 

[image]